# Easiet way to calculate the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}4x+24 & x-12 & x-12 & x-12 & x-12\\x-12 & 4x+24 & x-12 & x-12 &  x-12\\x-12 &x-12 &4x+24 & x-12 & x-12\\x-12 & x-12 & x-12 & 4x+24 & x-12\\ x-12 & x-12 & x-12 & x-12 & 4x+24\end{pmatrix}$$
Given the matrix above, what is the easiet way to calculate its determinant? I've tried getting as many zeroes on the first column for example, but I still end up with 2 non-zero elements. And it repeats for every minor, and becomes very tedious.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text or formulas. See
[here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem),
why. Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). For such matrices there is a general formula for its determinant - search it!

Comment: I would start by subtracting the first column from all the others.